# How to fill my object with the HTML value ? (array)

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `form` that allow the user to modify a file, and I'm having some troubles to replace in the file some values. I don't know how I should do the loop and replace in the object.

I need to keep the index of both like this:

```
obj.environment[0] = children[0]
obj.environment[1] = children[1]
```

and as you can see, maybe there are more `environment` in the form than in the `object` because the user added some, so it should add them after.

```js
myObj = {environment: ["a","b","c"]} 
$('#labelEnv').children('input').each(function () {
  myObj.environment[id] =  this.value
});
```

```css
.form-style-2{
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(blue, 0.8);
}
.form-style-2-heading{
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 label{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-2 label > span{
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:25%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.form-style-2 span.required{
  color:red;
}

.form-style-2 a{
  display: block;
}
.form-style-2 input.input-field {
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 4px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 31%;
}
.form-style-2 input.env, input.vol{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.form-style-2 input.nameModif{
  width: 50% !important;
}


.form-style-2 .input-field:focus{
  border: 1px solid #0C0;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif:hover{
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.form-style-2 input.cancelModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 input.cancelModif:hover{
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divCodeContainer">
        <div class="form-style-2">
          <div class="form-style-2-heading"></div>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label>
              <span>Container name
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field nameModif" value="" />
            </label>
            <label id="labelEnv">
              <span>Environment
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <a class="addEnv" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>&nbsp;</span>
              <input class="saveModif" type="button" value="Save" />
              <input class="cancelModif" type="button" value="Cancel" />
            </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**the snippet is not working and it's wrong because I don't know how I should make the loop**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `index` to your `.each()` like `.each(function (index)`

Then you can use `myObj.environment[index]`

```
$('#labelEnv').children('input').each(function (index) {
  myObj.environment[index] =  this.value
});
```

```js
myObj = {environment: ["a","b","c"]} 
$('#labelEnv').children('input').each(function (index) {
  myObj.environment[index] =  this.value
});

console.log(myObj)
```

```css
.form-style-2{
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(blue, 0.8);
}
.form-style-2-heading{
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 label{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-2 label > span{
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:25%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.form-style-2 span.required{
  color:red;
}

.form-style-2 a{
  display: block;
}
.form-style-2 input.input-field {
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 4px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 31%;
}
.form-style-2 input.env, input.vol{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.form-style-2 input.nameModif{
  width: 50% !important;
}


.form-style-2 .input-field:focus{
  border: 1px solid #0C0;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.form-style-2 input.saveModif:hover{
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.form-style-2 input.cancelModif{
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-style-2 input.cancelModif:hover{
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divCodeContainer">
        <div class="form-style-2">
          <div class="form-style-2-heading"></div>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label>
              <span>Container name
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field nameModif" value="" />
            </label>
            <label id="labelEnv">
              <span>Environment
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <a class="addEnv" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>&nbsp;</span>
              <input class="saveModif" type="button" value="Save" />
              <input class="cancelModif" type="button" value="Cancel" />
            </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *index* of `$.each()`

```
$('#labelEnv').children('input').each(function(index) {
    myObj.environment[index] = this.value
});
```

```js
myObj = {
  environment: ["a", "b", "c"]
}
$('#labelEnv').children('input').each(function(index) {
  myObj.environment[index] = this.value
});

console.log(myObj.environment);
```

```css
.form-style-2 {
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px 10px 2px 10px;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: rgba(blue, 0.8);
}

.form-style-2-heading {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.form-style-2 label {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-2 label>span {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 25%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.form-style-2 span.required {
  color: red;
}

.form-style-2 a {
  display: block;
}

.form-style-2 input.input-field {
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 4px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 31%;
}

.form-style-2 input.env,
input.vol {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.form-style-2 input.nameModif {
  width: 50% !important;
}

.form-style-2 .input-field:focus {
  border: 1px solid #0C0;
}

.form-style-2 input.saveModif {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.form-style-2 input.saveModif:hover {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}

.form-style-2 input.cancelModif {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.form-style-2 input.cancelModif:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divCodeContainer">
  <div class="form-style-2">
    <div class="form-style-2-heading"></div>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label>
              <span>Container name
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field nameModif" value="" />
            </label>
      <label id="labelEnv">
              <span>Environment
              </span>
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me a" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me b" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me c" />
              <input type="text" class="input-field env" value="replace me" />
              <a class="addEnv" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </label>
      <label>
              <span>&nbsp;</span>
              <input class="saveModif" type="button" value="Save" />
              <input class="cancelModif" type="button" value="Cancel" />
            </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not what I tried to say, with your example the `myObj` keeps `a,b,c` but I want to replace `a = first child` `b = second child` you see ?

Comment: It would works but @Carsten answered first, thank you for the time you gave me

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
myObj.environment = $('#labelEnv').children('input').get().map( e => e.value )
```

Comment: It would works too ! I chose to use the answer of @Carsten but thank you for this nice and short way to achieve it